# .NET processing queue communication between master and worker servers

Tags: .net, architecture, communication

I'm trying to figure out the best way to create a master - worker architecture for simple job delegation.

1 master process that delegates jobs to several worker processes.
- The master needs to continually run and delegate jobs to workers (and do other tasks).
- The workers (on different servers) just need to receive the job, process it and report back.
- the master process will receive a queue of jobs and will delegate them to worker nodes who will then process the request and notify the master that the job has been processed.  The master does not need to wait for the workers to complete but can just delegate the job and then receive an update from the worker when it has completed.

What would be the best way to facilitate this communication in .NET?  I already have class libraries that do the job processing but am looking for a good communication method.

MSMQ?
Windows Service?
Remoting?

Thanks

Comment: What are your reliability requirements? Will the master and workers be geographically spread or will they always be running on the same LAN?

Comment: They'll all be running in the same LAN.
Additionally, the master will need to receive inputs from a .net web app (if this can be done fairly easily), otherwise, it'll just receive updates by regularly polling the db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For exactly this purpose, I used WCF with net.tcp bindings, with a callback interface to let the Master Control Program know the job was done (yep, it was called "The MCP", the processes that initiated the jobs were called "Sark", and the network was referred to as the "Game Grid", go figure).

"Sark" was implemented as both a console app and a Windows Service (for ease of development and to "dip our toes" into a new worker machine), while The MCP was a long-running GUI. If I were to re-implement it, I'd probably make the Master Control a Windows Service as well, but it was advantageous to the IT department to see what jobs were scheduled and to pause the MCP when a backup job or other maintenance task was due. Today, I'd still make The MCP a service and just provide a GUI "remote control" for it.

The jobs were written as .Net DLL assemblies with an interface for invoking the task. "Sark" would copy the latest version of the binaries over a fileshare, create a new AppDomain, load and run the job within that AppDomain, then shut it down when it was done. This made it possible to update the jobs without having to restart either The MCP or the "Sarks".

In addition, each "Sark" instance also used MSMQ with short-lived messages (a timeout of 10 seconds) to report the load on each worker machine. The MCP would then use a weighted random pick to chose which worker machine to dispatch a job to. That is: if a machine reported that it was 80% idle, then it would get 80 'votes' to take the next scheduled task, which meant it was more likely than a machine that was only 10% idle. It was a reasonably effective way of distributing the load evenly while avoiding hotspots.

I chose net.tcp as the WCF binding to dispatch jobs and receive results because "fire and forget" did not work very well in practice. Failure happens: there would be out-of-memory exceptions, problems with the runtime on the server (a major one was when a task needed to work with FoxPro tables, and the ODBC FoxPro driver from Microsoft didn't come in a 64-bit version--a problem when we had a mix of 32-bit and 64-bit worker machines), or because of a hundred unexpected contingencies such as when the worker was on an IP address that was firewalled by the machine it wanted to talk to. An immediate response over the callback gave the MCP the option to re-assign the job to another worker on a different machine.

MSMQ, however, was perfect for reporting the health of the worker machines, because The MCP didn't have to be running in order for the workers to report their burden, and the short timeout on the messages meant the MCP wouldn't receive information that was too stale.

Comment: I'll look into WCF with the tcp bindings more.  Thanks for the suggestion.  Any great links for this (if you don't have any off the top of your head, don't worry, I'll definitely research this myself)

Comment: The main thing with the TCP bindings were that they supported callbacks (you define an interface with some methods for the slave servers to reply to the master in an asynchronous fashion--not possible with HTTP or MSMQ). I'll update my answer if I find any good links that help.

Answer (score 3):

MSMQ is a message transport protocol and it should work well for your scenario because the master server does not need an immediate response from the worker - "fire and forget". Moreover, it would allow workers to go down and receive a queue of messages when they are back up. You can use WCF as an abstraction over MSMQ - MSMQ is a type of binding. As far as hosting, windows service is an option, though you may want to look into [AppFabric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849), which hosts the services as IIS websites. With the new Auto Start feature available in Windows Server 2008 R2, this is a perfect alternative to windows services, especially for your type of application.

Comment: Would AppFabric make it easier for the master to also receive notifications via web services?  One of our other requirements is for the master to receive input from an external web app.  Thanks a lot for the great response

Comment: Actually, it looks like we won't be able to use AppFabric as we'll be hosting this on Windows Server 2003.  It looks pretty powerful though and I'll remember this for future projects